# Using interest money to make up for capital loss

Tags: banking

Assalamoualaikum,

If we have a capital deposited with interest in a savings bank account for necessity purposes, and now an amount of the capital is lost, can we take an equal amount from the interest to make up for the capital loss, and count the lost money as being part of the interest to be given to charity?

JazakAllah khairan